# Convert HashMap keys from String to int

Tags: java

I have a HashMap and a properties file that holds key/values. 
Properties file stores keys/values in this format "4,5=2"
I have built a method that loads properties from the file and it puts the pair of "keys/value" into a HashMap Array(String, Integer). But my problem is that I want each element of keys to be stored as an int, in order to use them as parameters to another method. Keys are stored as String.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

```
public static HashMap<String, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<>();

prop.load(input);
Enumeration<?> e = prop.propertyNames();
    while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
           key = (String) e.nextElement();
           intValue=Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty(key));
           hashMap.put(key, intValue);
```

Comment: Do the conversion when calling that *another* method.

Comment: Can't you simply parse the key to integer as you did for the value???

Comment: I agree with @AlessandroSantini. Why did you declare a `HashMap<String, Integer>` if you actually need a `HashMap<Integer, Integer>`?

Comment: @AlessandroSantini the problem is that there is not a single number in key. there are two keys, for example: "5,6" and I can't parse it to int.
I can only parse the value to int.

Comment: @VincentDurmont I have tried it but it doesn't work either. There are two numbers on the key pair. For example "5,6" and I can't parse it to an int.

Comment: You can split the String twice, first by ',' and then by '=', is this what your looking for?

Comment: @XhensB you read the key as a string, you split it using "," as a delimiter, and you put the value as many times as the keys that come out of the split.

Comment: @RoeyGolzarpoor I have also did that. I stored the numbers into two different arrays but then they were stored in unsorted way. I need to have them in a sorted way, because I need to enter into two "for loops" after that, and I have to compare each element of two arrays.

Comment: Which arrays? If you have several keys for a value, do `String[] keys = ((String)e.nextElement()).split(",");` then `for (String key : keys) { map.put(Integer.valueOf(key), Integer.valueOf(prop.getProperty(key)));`. It will add an entry for each key in the hashmap.

Comment: @AlessandroSantini I have done it. I split the string with a delimiter and parsed each of the numbers to int. Then, I saved each of them into a different array. But when I loop into arrays, they are unsorted and I don't know why. I need to have elements in the default order.

Comment: Why not combine the first two integers into a class (don't forget to override `equals` and `hashCode` though), and use that as a key?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes-owlstead I'm trying that now

Comment: Will the individual keys (4 and 5) be unique? So for example: there won't be a (4, 5) pair and a (0, 5) pair.

Comment: @Obicere yes, I need to have them unique

Comment: @XhensB then would it work putting both `<4, 2>` and `<5, 2>` into the map? Or do the keys need to be linked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you key seems to be a pair of integers, you need a Pair class to be used as a key. Then just access getFirst() or getSecond() to be used with your other api.

```
public class IntPair {
    private final int first;
    private final int second;

    public IntPair(int first, int second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 3;
        hash = 89 * hash + this.first;
        hash = 89 * hash + this.second;
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final IntPair other = (IntPair) obj;
        if (this.first != other.first) {
            return false;
        }
        if (this.second != other.second) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public int getFirst() {
        return first;
    }

    public int getSecond() {
        return second;
    }


}
```

Comment: I'll try this and I'll tell you if this works for me. Anyway, nice idea!

Answer (score 0):

just split the key-String by ","

```
public static HashMap<String, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<>();

prop.load(input);
Enumeration<?> e = prop.propertyNames();
while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
       String sKey = (String) e.nextElement();
       intValue = Integer.parseInt(prop.getProperty(sKey));
       String[] keys = sKey.split(",");
       for(String key: keys)
            hashMap.put(key, intValue);
```

Comment: Key has a pair of integers while HashMap stores 2 objects. Added the value, there are going to be three objects and that leads me to an error.